# Getting text from value

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo DropDownList and already I have assigned a values as well.

From jQuery function, I have a particular value and I need to know the text of the value.

Is there a way to get text from value??

I tried different ways, but not working.

```
var tempvalue = 4;
$("#ddlDocType").data("kendoDropDownList").dataItem(tempvalue);
```

Note: I don't want the selected drop down list text.

Comment: Please share what you have tried.

Comment: var tempvalue = 4;
$("#ddlDocType").data("kendoDropDownList").dataItem(tempvalue);

This is what I have tried Jayesh. If not can you please tell how can I iterate through the items of dropdownlist in kendo.

Comment: you can share your code what you write , i am unable to  understand what you actually want to do.

Comment: Any news on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var getText = function(id) {
    var ddl = $("#ddl").data("kendoDropDownList"),
        result = ddl.dataItems().filter(function(item) {
            return item.id == id;
        });

    var text = "";

    if (result.length > 0) {
        text = result[0].text;
    }

    return text;
};

var text = getText(1); // id 1
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/iZoBA)

Answer (score 0):

The `dataItem` will return the dataItem object.  In order to get the text, you need to find out what is the field used by the kendoDropDownList for the display using the `dataTextField` property.

```
var ddl = $("#ddlDocType").data("kendoDropDownList");
var dataItem = ddl.dataItem(4);
alert(dataItem[ddl.dataTextField]);
```

If you didn't specified a value for `dataTextField` when you initialized your kendoDropDownList, I think it will use `text` by default:

```
alert(dataItem.text);
```